# Write function in one line into ~/.bashrc

Tags: scripts, bashrc, syntax

Why when I try to write a function just in one line into `.bashrc` file,

```
list(){ ls -a }
```

I get error?

```
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line num: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

but when I write it in multi line it's ok?

```
list(){
    ls -a
}
```

Comment: There is an later, equivalent question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38595559/82216).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Functions in `bash` are essentially named compound commands (or code blocks). From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
Compound Commands
   A compound command is one of the following:
   ...
   { list; }
          list  is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list
          must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This  is  known
          as  a  group  command. 

...
Shell Function Definitions
   A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command  and
   executes  a  compound  command with a new set of positional parameters.
   ... [C]ommand is usually a list of commands between { and },  but
   may  be  any command listed under Compound Commands above.
```

There's no reason given, it's just the syntax.

Since the list in the one-line function given isn't terminated with a newline or a `;`, `bash` complains.

Answer (score 49):

There is a `;` needed at the end of the function:

```
list(){ ls -a ; }
```

should work.

The syntax of a function definition for bash is specified as

```
name () { list ; }
```

Note that it includes a `;` that is not part of the `list`.

That the `;` is required in this place is kind of a syntax anomaly. It is not `bash` specific, it's the same for `ksh`, but it the `;` is not required in `zsh`.

Answer (score 21):

The end of a single command (";") is implied by the newline.  In the oneline version `}` is parsed as an argument to the unterminated `ls -a` command.  Which you can see if you do:

```
$ foo(){ echo "a" }
}
$ foo
a }
```

See how the command inside the function declaration swallows the trailing curly brace?

Comment: Great explanation!  So it's *not* just a syntax anomaly; there's actually some logic to it.