# Syntax error near unexpected token `{workingDir=$(pwd)'

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax

Here is the problematic line in question.

```
function gradeUpdate() {workingDir=$(pwd); cd $GRADE_DIR; rm -Rf gradingScript/; git clone https://github.com/[redacted]/gradingScript/; cd $workingDir}
```

Of course, [redacted] in this case is the username of the repository owner. I can guarantee that `$GRADE_DIR` is a valid directory, and if I execute `cd $GRADE_DIR` in the Terminal, it works fine.

Also, if I enter all of the contents of the function (not the function itself) into the Terminal, then it works fine.

Comment: `function gradeUpdate() { workingDir=$(pwd); cd $GRADE_DIR; rm -Rf gradingScript/; git clone https://github.com/[redacted]/gradingScript/; cd $workingDir; }`

Comment: Space between curly braces and semicolon after last command  ...

Comment: @Ravexina Thank you! Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Related: [write function in one line into ~/.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521937/write-function-in-one-line-into-bashrc)