# How to get an aliased command to execute from a menu entry?

Tags: xubuntu, bashrc

I re-furbish PCs for a small non-profit and we use xubuntu cloned using clonezilla.  I am experiencing an issue where I set up an alias:

```
alias pkexec='pkexec /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY'
```

This works fine from the command line and from a menu entry that I edited on my work rig.  From my work rig, I get the password prompt that:

```
Authentication is required to run '/usr/bin/env'
```

I enter my password and /usr/bin/hardinfo opens as superuser.

However, when this is attempted on any of my 'clones', pkexec displays the password prompt:

```
Athentication is required to run /usr/bin/hardinfo
```

I enter my password and top show hardinfo starts then crashes or no longer appears as an executing program.  I know there is something different between my rig and my clones.  I don't know what is it.  I'm posting here for your comments and suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

@bacOn,

I set up the function in `.bashrc`

```
pkexec() { command pkexec /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY "$@" }
```

I get a syntax error when I run source .bashrc  syntax error unexpected token:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 146: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: .bashrc: line 146: `pkexec(){"command pkexec /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY "$@" "}'
```

@muru

I modified it and it now works.

pkexec(){
/usr/bin/pkexec /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY "$@"
}
source .bashrc and boom. it works on my home rig running mint from the commandline. but if I edit a menu entry pkexec /usr/bin/hardinfo,  I get the password windows saying that /usr/bin/hardinfo requires authentication to run as root. hardinfo crashes.

But even after all your help, my question still remains, What could have changed on my work rig that would cause a cloned imaged to not work as expected.  What troubleshooting steps might assist me in digging into the weeds on an issue that may/may not otherwise affect out future imaged machines.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I'm not sure of the issue, but have you considered taking one of your cloned images, and booting it up in a VM? That might allow you to debug the issue...

Comment: No actually, I havn't.  I don't think I know how to go about that.  I mean I can install virtualbox (what I am familiar with) but actually cloning the image to a vm,  I don't know.  But I am game to learn.

Comment: use a function instead.

Comment: Hi @bac0n,  I havn't used/setup a function before.  Not sure how that might look like.

Comment: function is use much the same way `pkexec(){ command pkexec env ... ... "$@"; }` you can ethier use `command` as I have done or full path to the real pkexec command or you will get a race condition.

Comment: You need the `;` before the closing `}` if you put the function definition all in one line: https://askubuntu.com/a/521943/158442